# How do I get the remote hostname of the server?

Tags: postgresql, debian

Can I use the hostname of the server in a PostgreSQL `SELECT` statement? The following may be close but apparently does not quite work:

```
\set x \! hostname
select :x;
```

This is for PostgreSQL 9.6 on Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I think what you're looking for is [`gethostname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html). That's not called anywhere in the [PostgreSQL source code.](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=gethostname&type=) Nor is `utsname` or any kernel interface into this.

What is called is `getaddrinfo` that provides a `CANONNAME` but that's essentially just your own method of addressing the server not the "symbolic hostname". If you need the hostname, you'll have to build a C-extension that does just that. Or, use a third party procedural language, like perl `plperlu`, that has that support (through `Sys::Hostname` or `Net::Domain`, see `perldoc -q hostname`); or, alternatively through javascript with `plv8` that has [`os.hostname()`](https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/os.html#os.hostname).

Another method would be simply reading the file `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`.

It's a database, not a remote administration utility. You can't really fault it for not doing this.

Comment: So you suggest there is now way to "pipe" the output from `\! hostname`  (when executed from inside PostgreSQL) into an SQL statement?

Comment: @rookie09 do you want the hostname of the client, or the server? The server doesn't provide shell access to the client, through the client. When you do `\!` you're accessing the shell of the client, not the server.

Comment: Extellent point, thx.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has 2 functions for getting server address information. `inet_server_addr()` and `inet_server_port()` which provide ip address and port information of the server.

However I don't know a direct way for getting hostname. So, you may try this;

You can use postgresql.conf to create a custom configuration and use [current_setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) function to get that value. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476062/setting-a-configuration-parameter-for-functions-implemented-in-pl-pgsql) is detailed description.

For other system functions you can check [System Information Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) section of the documentation.

Comment: I need the (symbolic) hostname, not the (numeric) IP address of the server.

Comment: if its not dynamic then use custom setting option